# How click over an element with specific string length, in CasperJS?

Tags: click, casperjs

I use CasperJS and i want click over an element (**span**) with specific length string. For example, I want click over span with 5 characters length.

```
<span>ABCDE</span>
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to click an element based on its content length, then there are multiple ways to achieve this. XPath provides the easiest way to do this using the `string-length(string)` function.

- If one of the text nodes of an element has a specific length `y`:

  ```js
  casper.click(x("//span[string-length(text())=" + y + "]"));
  ```
- If all the content needs to be of a certain size (equivalent to the previous suggestion of there are no other nodes besides a single text node):

  ```js
  casper.click(x("//span[string-length(.)=" + y + "]"));
  ```
- If whitespace is a problem, then you should remove that:

  ```js
  casper.click(x("//span[string-length(normalize-space(text()))=" + y + "]"));
  casper.click(x("//span[string-length(normalize-space(.))=" + y + "]"));
  ```

---

The XPath helper is given through `var x = require('casper').selectXPath;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @artjom B. . This work for me and you're a best friend for me.

Comment: @HosseinGanjyar That's right. He gave me many helpful advices about CasperJS... I think my company should pay him for his suggestions...

Comment: @Sayakiss, I agree your oponion. Thanks Artjom B.